# How to access EC2 function using command line or otherwise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have stored a javascript file on an Amazon EC2 instance and now I want to use it as an api. How do I get the endpoint url for this function? I mean I want to invoke this function by giving some input parameters. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you wish to run a function on an EC2 instance? Why not run it as Lambda (there are valid reasons for each choice)? Is it a web application? Are you running a web server on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can make lambda function on aws on Node.js, then adding trigger with API gateway.

More datail you can see here https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzvRQMJ9HDiSQMe68cti8cupI0mzLk1Gc

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, you need to configure your inbound traffic and open up a port where you can bind your application to (commonly use PORT 80 - HTTP - if you want to access through your browser). Here a link to their docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

As a next step you need to bind your application directly to the opened port or set an proxy that will forward the inbound traffic on the opened port to the port your application is bind to.

---

If this two steps are done, you should be able to access your api through amazons Public DNS (IPv4) you get automatically assigned when creating an instance or an public IP if you have one assigned to that instance

Comment: I didn't understand the above steps completely.Could you pleas elaborate a little? How do I bind my application to a port?

Comment: Basically what I want to do is this: I have a lambda function through which I want to invoke this EC2 function.